# UITextView Not Scrolling When Text is Assigned

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating an app which has the UIImageView and UITextView. I fetch the text and the image from the server but when I assign a lot of text to the UITextView the UITextView does not scroll. There are few times that it starts scrolling with a lot of text. I am not sure what I am doing wrong? But most of the time it does not scroll and looks frozen. I checked the output window and I do not see any constraints being broken.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject]!, inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {

    if beacons.count == 0 {
        return
    }

    for beacon in beacons as! [CLBeacon] {

       // we are only interested in beacons that are near or immediate!
        if beacon.proximity == .Near || beacon.proximity == .Immediate {

        let closestTourBeacon = beaconByMajorAndMinorId(beacon.major, minorId: beacon.minor)

        if self.lastBeacon == nil {
            self.lastBeacon = closestTourBeacon
        }
        else if isEqualToLastBeacon(closestTourBeacon)
        {
            continue
        }
        else {
            self.lastBeacon = closestTourBeacon
        }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                // vibrate the phone
                //AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))

                println("Assinging the text property")

                self.textTextView.text = closestTourBeacon.text <<=== THIS LINE
                self.title = closestTourBeacon.title
                self.photoImageView.load(closestTourBeacon.imageURL!)

                let originalFrame = self.photoImageView.frame
                self.photoImageView.center = CGPointMake(self.photoImageView.center.x, -100)

                UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionNone, animations: { () -> Void in

                    self.photoImageView.frame = originalFrame

                    }, completion: { (finished :Bool) -> Void in

                })
        })

        }

    }

}
```

UPDATE: I have also noted that when the app launch for the first time the UITextView is completely frozen even though there is lot of text to scroll. After that if I keep trying to scroll the UITextView and fetch and setText with new data it comes out of the frozen state and starts to scroll without any problems.

Comment: `self.textTextView.text = closestTourBeacon.text <<=== THIS LINE` I see you setting the text but I don't see you asking to scroll to any particular part of the text. If that's what you want, why don't you ask for that?

Comment: I don't want it to scroll to certain part of the text. I just want it to have the scrolling feature when the text is assigned. It does not even scroll period.

Answer (score 1):

If it's freezing take it off the main queue.

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);

    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
        //update text
    });
    //Release queue
    dispatch_release(myQueue);
```

Also check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvsEhDEGO_k I think your problem may be its updating too fast

Comment: The code results in runtime error saying that updated the text can only run in the main thread and not on the background thread.

Comment: Yes you can only update the UI on the main queue, so do the calculations inside the Background queue and update the UI as you get data

Comment: Are you only assigning the beacon major and minor to the text? It might be updating way to fast to keep up with that. Im updating my answer WITH A LINK

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses! Although I did not found why it was happening but I was able to find a work around. I now force it to scroll after assigning text.

```
 self.textTextView.text = closestTourBeacon.text
                    // scroll to get out of the frozen mode 

                    self.textTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(1, 1))
```

Comment: Yup, this is basically what I was suggesting in my comment above.